# I am facing problem in pre-populating form by hooks

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

So, i want to reuse the form component for creating and editing the meetup data. but, the problem i am facing is that i want to pass the meetup data to meetupForm component when isEdit is true and use that data to initalize the input field, but its not working as suppose to.

useInput hook for handling the input

```
import { useReducer } from "react";

const inputStateReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "INPUT") {
    console.log(action.value);
    return { value: action.value, isTouched: state.isTouched };
  }
  if (action.type === "BLUR") {
    return { value: state.value, isTouched: true };
  }
  if (action.type === "RESET") {
    return { isTouched: false, value: "" };
  }
  return state;
};

const useInput = (validateValue, initalValue = "") => {
  const [inputState, disptach] = useReducer(inputStateReducer, {
    value: initalValue,
    isTouched: false,
  });
  console.log("inputState.value:", inputState.value);

  const valueIsValid = validateValue(inputState.value);
  const hasError = !valueIsValid && inputState.isTouched;
  const valueChangeHandler = (event) => {
    disptach({ type: "INPUT", value: event.target.value });
  };
  const isTouchHandler = (event) => {
    disptach({ type: "BLUR" });
  };
  const reset = () => {
    disptach({ type: "RESET" });
  };

  return {
    value: inputState.value,
    isValid: valueIsValid,
    hasError,
    valueChangeHandler,
    isTouchHandler,
    reset,
  };
};
export default useInput;
```

MeetupForm component

```
import { FormLabel, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

import { useState, useMemo, useEffect } from "react";

import useInput from "../../Hooks/useInput";
import imageIcon from "../../assests/imageicon.png";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const MeetUpForm = ({ url, isEdit = false, meetup }) => {
  const [currentMeetup, setCurrentMeetup] = useState(meetup);
  
  
  const [formError, setFormError] = useState(true);
  const [eventImage, setEventImage] = useState(null);
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const [shouldUpload, setShouldUpload] = useState(null); // to decide if upload should be done or not
  const [Date, setDate] = useState(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [meetupError, setMeetupError] = useState(true);
  
  const {
    value: enteredName,
    isValid: enteredNameIsValid,
    hasError: nameInputError,
    valueChangeHandler: nameChangeHandler,
    isTouchHandler: nameBlurHandler,
    reset: resetName,
  } = useInput(
    (value) => value.trim() !== "",
    isEdit ? currentMeetup.name : ""
    );
    const {
      value: enteredAddress,
      isValid: enteredAddressIsValid,
      hasError: addressInputError,
      valueChangeHandler: addressChangeHandler,
      isTouchHandler: addressBlurHandler,
      reset: resetAddress,
    } = useInput(
      (value) => value.trim() !== "",
      isEdit ? currentMeetup.address : ""
      );
      
      const {
        value: enteredDescription,
        isValid: enteredDescriptionIsValid,
        hasError: discriptionInputError,
        valueChangeHandler: descriptionChangeHandler,
        isTouchHandler: descriptionBlurHandler,
        reset: resetDescription,
      } = useInput(
        (value) => value.trim() !== "",
        isEdit ? currentMeetup.description : ""
        );
        
        
        
        useEffect(() => {
          setCurrentMeetup(meetup);
        }, [meetup]);
        console.log("currentMeetup.name:", currentMeetup.name);
  const sumbitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(enteredAddress, enteredDescription, enteredName);
    if (
      enteredDescriptionIsValid &&
      enteredAddressIsValid &&
      enteredNameIsValid
    ) {
      setShouldUpload(true);
    }
  };
  const formData = useMemo(() => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("enteredAddress", enteredAddress);
    data.append("enteredName", enteredName);
    data.append("enteredDescription", enteredDescription);
    data.append("image", eventImage);
    data.append("date", Date);
    return data;
  }, [enteredAddress, enteredName, enteredDescription, eventImage, Date]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // post the data to backend

    if (!shouldUpload) return;

    const uploadData = async () => {
      try {
        const method = isEdit ? "PUT" : "POST";
        const response = await fetch(isEdit ? `${url}/${meetup.id}` : url, {
          method,
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
          body: formData,
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
          console.log("Error:", response.status);
          setFormError(true);
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data.message);
        if (data.message === "Meetup created successfully") {
          navigate("/home");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error file loading", error);
        setMeetupError(true);
      }
      setShouldUpload(false);
    };
    uploadData();
  }, [shouldUpload, formData, token, navigate, url, isEdit, meetup]);

  return (
    <div className="relative xl:3/5 flex flex-col justify-center max-xl:padding-x align-middle gap-5 max-container">
      {!formError && (
        <div className="border bg-red rounded-full">
          <h1>Something went wrong try again</h1>
        </div>
      )}
      {!meetupError && (
        <div className="border bg-red rounded-full">
          <h1>Meetup error</h1>
        </div>
      )}
      <form
        onSubmit={sumbitHandler}
        className="relative xl:3/5 flex flex-col justify-center max-xl:padding-x align-middle gap-5 max-container"
      >
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <FormLabel className="items-start justify-start text-start font-palanquin pb-2">
            Your Name
          </FormLabel>
          <TextField
            type="text"
            fullWidth
            id="fullWidth"
            value={enteredName}
            color={nameInputError ? "primary" : "secondary"}
            variant="outlined"
            onChange={nameChangeHandler}
            onBlur={nameBlurHandler}
          ></TextField>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <FormLabel className="items-start justify-start text-start font-palanquin pb-2">
            Event Address
          </FormLabel>
          <TextField
            type="text"
            value={enteredAddress}
            color={enteredAddressIsValid ? "primary" : "secondary"}
            variant="outlined"
            onChange={addressChangeHandler}
            onBlur={addressBlurHandler}
          ></TextField>
        </div>
        <FormLabel>Event's Poster</FormLabel>
        <div className="border-2 border-slate-700 rounded-md py-3 px-6">
          <input
            className="opacity-0 w-full z-5 mb-[-10px] "
            type="file"
            name="image"
            id="image"
            accept="/image*"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setEventImage(e.target.files[0]);
            }}
            alt="event poster image"
          ></input>
          <img className="w-[40px] h-[40px] z-0" src={imageIcon} alt="hello" />
        </div>
        <FormLabel>Event's Date</FormLabel>
        <TextField
          type="date"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setDate(e.target.valueAsDate);
          }}
          variant="outlined"
        ></TextField>
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <FormLabel className="items-start justify-start text-start font-palanquin pb-2">
            Enter Event's Description
          </FormLabel>
          <textarea
            className="my-3 pb-40 pt-2 px-3 border-2 border-slate-700 rounded-md focus:ring focus:ring-blue-200"
            type="text"
            value={enteredDescription}
            color={enteredDescriptionIsValid ? "primary" : "secondary"}
            onChange={descriptionChangeHandler}
            onBlur={descriptionBlurHandler}
            row={4}
            cols={1}
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className=" bg-[#dc143c] text-center text-slate-200 rounded-full font-palanquin font-medium text-lg px-3 py-4 mx-8 "
        >
          Add Event
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MeetUpForm;
```

Please help me or suggest me any alternative way of doing this!

I tried to reuse the meetupform component, but got stuck on prepopulating the data via custom hook

Answer (score 0):

Seems you should refactor the `useInput` hook a bit so it can reinitialize the state value when the `initialValue` argument changes. Move the reducer function into the hook body so it can reset to the initial value and use a `useEffect` hook to dispatch the reset action.

Example:

```js
const useInput = (validateValue, initialValue = "") => {

  // Reducer function moved into useInput function scope to 
  // close over initial value
  const inputStateReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "INPUT":
        return { ...state, value: action.value };

      case "BLUR":
        return { ...state, isTouched: true };

      case "RESET":
        // Reset to current initial value
        return { isTouched: false, value: initialValue };

      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  const [{ isTouched, value }, dispatch] = useReducer(inputStateReducer, {
    value: initialValue,
    isTouched: false
  });

  const isValid = validateValue(value);

  const hasError = !isValid && isTouched;

  const valueChangeHandler = (event) => {
    dispatch({ type: "INPUT", value: event.target.value });
  };

  const isTouchHandler = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "BLUR" });
  };

  const reset = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "RESET" });
  };

  // Initial value changed, reset input state
  useEffect(() => {
    reset();
  }, [initialValue]);

  return {
    value,
    isValid,
    hasError,
    valueChangeHandler,
    isTouchHandler,
    reset
  };
};
```

### Demo

[image: Edit i-am-facing-problem-in-pre-populating-form-by-hooks]